# Date Time Countdown with removing decimals and having time display time left in each category

Tags: javascript, html, time, countdown

Originally, found a partial answer to a countdown problem I was having here 

("Cymen" Thanks for your answer!) 
How would I go about preventing the countdown from using decimals in the remaining time left?
Also, how can I make it so that it will only say the seconds left in the minute, minutes left it the hour, and so on like on this website that happens to have the exact date and time I'm trying to count down to....
 
http://50onfire.com/dc/

Here is what I have edited Cymen's code to: 
http://jsfiddle.net/McdSV/

HTML

```
<div class="countdown"></div>
    <p class="labels">
        <span class="weeks">WEEKS </span>
        <span class="days">DAYS </span>
        <span class="hours">HOURS </span>
        <span class="minutes">MINUTES </span>
        <span class="seconds">SECONDS </span>
    </p>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var date = new Date(2014, 11, 4, 19);
    var $display = $('.countdown');
    countdown($display, date);
    setInterval(function () { countdown($display, date); }, 1000);
});

var offset = get_time_zone_offset();

function countdown($display, collision) {
    var now = new Date();
    now.setHours(now.getHours() + (offset-5));
    var seconds = Math.ceil((collision.getTime() - now.getTime()) * 0.001);
    var minutes = Math.ceil(seconds/60);
    var hours = Math.ceil(seconds/60/60 * 10)/10;
    var days = Math.ceil((seconds/60/60/24) * 100)/100;
    var weeks = Math.ceil((days/7) * 100)/100;
    $display.html
    (
        '<p class="numbers">' + 
        collision + ((offset != 5) ? ' with time zone offset of ' + (offset-5) + ' hours' : '') +
        '<br><br><span id="weeks">' + weeks + '</span>' + 
        '<span id="days">' + days + '</span>' +
        '<span id="hours">' +hours + '</span>' +
        '<span id="minutes">' +minutes + '</span>' +
        '<span id="seconds">' +seconds + '</span>' +
        '</p>'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the code below just before  **$display.html**

```
seconds = parseInt(seconds);
minutes = parseInt(minutes);
hours = parseInt(hours); 
days = parseInt(days);
weeks = parseInt(weeks);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

http://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/

They are providing the same as you want and also giving nice description and tutorial for the same. also you can easily modified the code if you wish.

or

I have modified your demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/patelbharat001/McdSV/154/

In this i changed your process for getting difference,

check it, may help you.

```
    var seconds1=Math.floor(((endDate-startDate)%(24*60*60*1000))/1000)%60%60;

    var seconds= ((60 + parseInt(seconds1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this ?

```
Sat Jul 21 2012 15:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
seconds: 5
minutes: 0
hours: 13
days: 2
weeks: 119
```

**JS Fiddle Link:** [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/McdSV/155/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var date = new Date(2012, 6, 21, 15, 30);
    var $display = $('#countdown');
    countdown($display, date);
    setInterval(function () { countdown($display, date); }, 1000);
});

var offset = get_time_zone_offset();

function countdown($display, collision) {
    var now = new Date();
    now.setHours(now.getHours() + (offset-5));
    var seconds = Math.ceil((collision.getTime() - now.getTime()) * 0.001);
    var minutes = Math.ceil(seconds/60);
    var hours = Math.ceil(seconds/60/60 * 10)/10;
    var days = Math.ceil((seconds/60/60/24) * 100)/100;
    var weeks = Math.ceil((days/7) * 100)/100;
    //seconds = seconds - Math.floor(seconds / 60)*60

    $display
        .html
        (
            '<p>' + 
            collision + ((offset != 5) ? ' with time zone offset of ' + (offset-5) + ' hours' : '') +

            '<br>seconds: ' + Math.abs( Math.floor(-seconds / 60)*60 + seconds) +
            '<br>minutes: ' + Math.abs( Math.floor(-minutes / 60)*60 + minutes) +
            '<br>hours: ' + Math.floor(Math.abs( Math.floor(-hours / 24)*24 + hours)) +
            '<br>days: ' + Math.floor(Math.abs( Math.floor(-days / 7)*7 + days)) +
            '<br>weeks: ' + Math.floor(-weeks) +
            '</p>'
        );
}

function get_time_zone_offset() {
     var current_date = new Date( );
     var gmt_offset = current_date.getTimezoneOffset( ) / 60;
     return gmt_offset;
}
```